# Can we use percentage in clip css?

Tags: html, css

want to user percentage in this css

```
clip: rect(0px,400px,800px,0px);
```

I want to give size in percentage instead of pixel to handle mobile view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the [`clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip) property, which is deprecated, you can use the [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) property instead, and use a `polygon` (or even an SVG). For a polygon, you define it in `x y` pairs for the coordinate: `0 0` would be the top left, `100% 0` would be the top right, etc.

Take this example one for instance, it will clip the square divs to 65% width and 30% height.

```css
div { margin: 10px; background: #0095ee; border: 10px solid #000; }
#a { width: 100px; height: 100px; } #b { width: 200px; height: 200px; }

div {
  clip-path: polygon( 0 0, 65% 0, 65% 30%, 0 30% );
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is `inset()` where you can use percentage and it works the same way as padding/margin:

```css
.box {
  margin: 10px;
  background: #0095ee;
  border: 10px solid #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  clip-path: inset(10% 5% 0 50%); /* top left bottom right*/
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

> `inset() = inset( <shape-arg>{1,4} [round <border-radius>]? )`
>
> Defines an inset rectangle.
>
> When all of the first four arguments are supplied they represent the top, right, bottom and left offsets from the reference box inward that define the positions of the edges of the inset rectangle. These arguments follow the syntax of the margin shorthand, that let you set all four insets with one, two or four values.
>
> The optional `<‘border-radius’>` argument(s) define rounded corners for the inset rectangle using the border-radius shorthand syntax.
> A pair of insets in either dimension that add up to more than the used dimension (such as left and right insets of 75% apiece) define a shape enclosing no area. For this specification, this results in an empty float area. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-shapes-1/#supported-basic-shapes)</sup>